# How can I append an array as column to another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have this problem in Python and I cannot figure out how I can do this. I have three arrays:

Two of the form:

```
array1 ([ 1,  2, 3])
array2 ([ 4,  5, 6])
```

and one of the form:

```
array3 ([ [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])
```

What I want is an array from these two arrays which has three columns, in such a way, that the 2D array is in the center:

```
array  ([1, [1, 2, 3], 4],
        [2, [2, 3, 4], 5],
        [3, [3, 4, 5], 6])
```

I am able to join the first two arrays by using e.g. `np.c_[array1, array2]`. 
I can do `np.c_[array1, array3, array2]` as well, but then I get

```
array  ([1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [3, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't *want* to do this with `numpy` arrays.  Jagged arrays are a bad idea.

Comment: This is for an exercise, so I don't have a choice. Any idea?

Comment: `[list(el) for el in zip(array1, array3, array2)]`

Comment: The desired display is flawed.  It looks lilke a 3 element tuple, where the elements are lists that contain numbers and lists.  The `array` word is just tacked on.  It's not a valid array constructor or display, not even for `object` dtype.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a bad idea**.  [Read up on how `numpy` stores data](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/internals.html) and you will understand that `numpy` is not meant to store jagged arrays with mixed data types.

That being said, all you are asking for is your three input elements zipped together.  If you really want to store this data you could simply store it as a `list`, which would be preferable to an `ndarray`

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
c = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])
```

---

You can accomplish this with a list comprehension and `zip`

```
np.array([list(el) for el in zip(a, c, b)], dtype=object)
```

```
array([[1, array([1, 2, 3]), 4],
       [2, array([2, 3, 4]), 5],
       [3, array([3, 4, 5]), 6]], dtype=object)
```

---

You **must** specify a `dtype` of `object` since you are setting an array element with a sequence.